# Need help writing this sql query into laravel query builder

Tags: sql, laravel

```
SELECT *
FROM Movies 
WHERE (SELECT AVG(Score) 
FROM Reviews WHERE MovieId=Id)>2
```

Is it even possible to write subqueries in laravel query builder?

Comment: did you set the relationship between `Movie` and `Review` ?

Comment: I did but both eloquent and query builder in laravel are very confusing to me and i can't find solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you show what you have tried with Query Builder so far to build this query?

Comment: Check the [subqueries](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses) and [havingRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw) docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('movies')
      ->join('reviews', 'reviews.movieId', '=', 'movies.id)
      ->select(DB::raw('avg(reviews.score) as score'))
      ->where([
            ['reviews.movieId', '>', 2],
            // [ if any other clause]
            ])
      ->get();
```